# Setting the domain correctly for cookies

Tags: php, cookies, http-headers, session-cookies, setcookie

I have a script where $site (location of where it's hosted) will either be in the format of a subdomain e.g. 'something.domain.com' or a domain 'domain.com', and the cookies are handled like the following:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', $site); //for sessions

setcookie($name, $value, $expiry, '/', $site, false, true); //for others
```

My question is the script's canonical url is non-www and I don't want other subdomains for various reasons (including security) being able to access/read the cookies (e.g. 'www.something.domain.com' or 'www.domain.com' or 'somethingelse.domain.com' or 'www.somethingelse.domain.com'), so would you say the above will work okay (providing $site does not proceed with www. or .)?

I have searched around (also referred to php.net) and believe the above will be okay from my understanding - but wanted reassurance as I had read many conflicting/confusing information!

Edit: If the above won't work - I thought about maybe setting $site to false (the .htaccess code would enforce access only via non-www)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't fully understand your question. But in general, if `$site == 'domain.com'`, while a cookie is being set, then any scripts at `'domain.com'`, `'foo.domain.com'`, `'www.something.domain.com'`, etc. will all have access to that cookie (any site that ends with `'domain.com'`, regardless of the canonical url of the script that set the cookie). Similarly, if `$site == 'something.domain.com'`, then scripts at `'something.domain.com'`, `'foo.something.domain.com'`, etc. will have access to it (anything that ends with `'something.domain.com'`).